# What are the weapons made of that are employed by the Praetorian Guard of Moff Gideon's Imperial remnant?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In Season 3 Episode 7 of *The Mandalorian*, we see

> the three Shadow Council Praetorian Guards assigned to Moff Gideon engage Paz Viszla in combat. Their weapons appear to pierce his beskar armor when they kill him.

Wookiepedia lacks information on the weapons of these Praetorian Guards, and the reference to Snoke's guards only provides lightsaber-resistant weapons that do not match those employed by Gideon's guards. What are these weapons made of that would enable them to pierce beskar so easily? [image: Praetorian Guard stabbing Paz]

Comment: They just find the gaps between the plates.

Comment: Didn't one of them stab him straight through the chest plate?

Comment: Adding photo to show it

Comment: Hmm, can't really tell. I though it was just under the edge of the front plate.

Comment: do we know if Paz Viszla has full beskar, or is he wearing some durasteel?

Comment: I rewatched the scene and it looks like it goes right through the armor. It is on the lower left (as to the wearer), but it does seem to go through the armor, not under it

Comment: @Turbo his armor withstood the Darksaber in The Book of Boba Fett

Comment: Also Wookiepedia confirms that is is beskar with reinforced plates

Comment: Suggestion: for those who haven't seen the episode, a spoiler tag would be beneficial.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how to do that. The style guide at the bottom only showed me how to do quotes, italics, and code. I don't usually need more than that.

Comment: With what I know from my research, beskar is the only material that could serve this purpose, but I haven't found anything definitive on that.

Answer (score 1):

According to StarWars.com its a [electro chain whip](https://www.starwars.com/databank/electro-chain-whip). -

> The Bilari electro-chain whip is a weapon used by two of Snoke’s Praetorian Guards to defend the Supreme Leader. An **electro-plasma filament is threaded through the whip’s articulated segments**, packing enough power to kill an opponent. The whip can be stiffened to act like a bludgeon in combat.

It does not look like a whip in the episode because its been "stiffened to act like a bludgeon" as mentioned above.

As to how they were able to pierce beskar , the internet lacks information

Comment: That was a weapon of Snoke's guard, and if you check the images does not match the weapons used by Gideon's guards. The weapons are too short to be the whip and they have energy on the exterior along their entire length,  whereas the whip only has it in segments.

Comment: Also my question was specifically what they were made of and how they pierce beskar.

Comment: @JeremyNielsen, I have checked the image and only then concluded that it is indeed the same weapon, maybe some minor colour or design changes but otherwise its the same weapon

Comment: @JeremyNielsen, and i have answered your question of what they were made of with - "electro plasma filament" how does that not answer the question?

Comment: I am unsure if it currently had an answer, which is why I asked. If it doesn't have an answer currently, it will sit around until it does have an answer. In-universe, plasma cannot pierce beskar. Thus the electro-plasma filament would not pierce the beskar. I apologize for the poor wording in the question and will clarify that immediately

Comment: @JeremyNielsen The wookieepedia page on beskar cites The Star Wars Book (which I don't have a copy of) saying that beskar can withstand lightsaber strikes "for a limited time", which suggests that forms of disruptive energy CAN pierce it after all.

Comment: Correct, also suggested in Season 2 of The Mandalorian. However, these weapons went right through like a hot knife into butter. Not even lightsabers do that. Plus the plasma does not extend to the tip. The tip is solid, as one can see on the Wookiepedia page for these specific Praetorian Guards.

Comment: @shanu it would seem that you were in fact correct about what the weapon was, but the question had to do with the material that would allow it to stab through beskar with ease.